# Name of $a*b=c$ and $b*a=-c$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, terminology, noncommutative-algebra

$A_+=(A,+,0,-)$ is a noncommutative group where inverse elements are $-a$

$A_*=(A,*)$ is not associative and is not commutative

$\mathbf A=(A,+,*)$ is a structure where

1) if $a*b=c$ then $b*a=-c$ holds and

2) $(a*b)+a=b+(a*b)$

> A-How is called the structure $\mathbf A$?
>
> B-What is the name of 1) and 2) in abstract algebra (even not in the same structure)?
>
> C-and what is this structure? It Has been already studied and does it have other intresting (or obvious) properties that I don't see?

Thanks in advance and I apologize for errors in my english.

**Update**

As Lord_Farin explained to me, $\mathbf A=(A,+,*)$ can't be a structure (closed) since the property 2) imply that $a*0$ and $0*a$ are assorbing elements of $(A,+)$ and that is impossible because $A_+$ is a non-trivial group (in the definition).

Anyways I notice that my questions B (about property 2) ) and C are still open in the case of a "generic" $A_+$ .

Comment: I don't understand condition (1). What is $c$? It will always be true that $a*b=c$ for *some* $c$, so are you saying that $b*a=-a$ for all $b$?

Comment: If 1) is supposed to contain $b * a = -c$ in place of $b*a = c$, I believe this is called _anticommutativity_ of $*$ in some contexts (but usually in a context of rings IIRC). 2) doesn't look familiar to me.

Comment: @Lord_Farin That sounds like a reasonable guess at what was meant (and it would usually be written $a*b=-b*a$, to avoid unnecessary $c$s).

Comment: sorry i typed it wrong, @Lord_Farin is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 2) we have $(a*0)+a = 0+(a*0) = a*0 = (a*0)+0$ which contradicts the fact that $(A,+)$ is a group (which implies "left-multiplication" by $(a*0)$, i.e. $x \mapsto (a*0)+x$, is injective). Thus the structure $(A,+,*)$ cannot exist.

Comment: Why if $+$ forms a group $*$ must be injective?

Comment: It needn't. But the operation $x \mapsto (a*0)+x$ must be (for its inverse is $x \mapsto -(a*0)+x$).

Comment: Is maybe possible that $(a*0)$ behaves on $(A,+)$ like zero behaves for arithmetic multiplication, as absorbing element.If is so that can make $\mathbf A$ a structure again?What am I missing?

Comment: Groups cannot have absorbing elements. For, what would be their inverse? Cf. [this proof](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Group_with_Zero_Element_is_Trivial) which shows that I forgot about the trivial group.

Comment: Ah ok, so i can rethink to my question replacing (A,+,*) with  (A/ \{ a*0,0*a \},+,*), that make it more intresting (like making (\mathbb R,\times) a group ) is not the same? (i don't know how to show the TeX)

Comment: Think about it some more. You might also use some draftpaper to experiment a bit. In general, things can get ugly if the operation is nonassociative. However, this site is not designed to discuss possible algebraic structures in comments. As for this question, you could accept my answer to avoid more people spending time on something that doesn't exist.

Comment: I'll not accept your question now, even if it replyed about the existence of the structure (it doesn't if defined like i did). I'll wait for comment about the name of the property 2) or structures with similar properties.Thanks you anyways. And yea! I'll think about it more.

Comment: isn't this a dot product algebra .. vectorial or dot product :)

Comment: Sorry, can you be more clear?I don't know what is a dot product @JoseGarcia

Comment: @JoseGarcia what is a dot product algebra and, is it (if yes how) related to my structure?